# free $G$-action on a topological space

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-actions

Does existence of a free finite $G$-action on a topological space invariant under homotopy? In other words, let $X$ be a free $G$ topological space which is homotopic with a topological space $Y$. Does this assumption imply of the existence of a free action of $G$ on Y? Additionally, assume $X$ and $Y$ are finite CW-complex and $G$ is a finite group.

Comment: What can you say about contractible spaces ?

Comment: As I know, at least finite contractible CW-complex cannot admits a free action.

Comment: Yeah but some spaces aren't finite CW-complexes. What about $\mathbb{R}$ for instance ?

Comment: Yes! I got it! For example, $\mathbb{R}$ can act on itself freely. What if we limit the question to finite groups and finite CW-complexes?

Comment: Take $S^1\subset\mathbb{C}$ to which you've added the line segment $[1,2]$. Can $\mathbb{Z/2Z}$ act freely on it ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, it cannot exist. Any action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ must always fix $1$!